# Every chef commands gets error (Mac OS X)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra

It looks like following:

```
$chef-client --version
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:774:in `block in activate_dependencies': can't satisfy 'mime-types (~> 1.16)', already activated 'mime-types-2.0' (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/bin/chef-client:22:in `'
```

It is mean that I should reinstall ruby?or updated it? What kinds of  commands should be used?

Comment: chef-client uses embedded ruby. how did you install chef-client?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really forget the way I install it. May be chef was installed twice with different methods,curl and gems

Comment: I would uninstall all possible chef-client stuff and then will do a clean install. Its better that way instead of troubleshooting the existing non-healthy chef-client.

Comment: Yes，I intended to do this, But I troubled with the what commands should be used for uninstall chef-*, Also, needn't I uninstall ruby and rubygems?

Comment: don't know about mac. on linux I would use `yum/rpm` (RHEL based) OR `aptitude/dpkg` (ubuntu based) commands to get rid of existing chef-client binaries. No, dont do anything to ruby. In all likelihood, if it is embedded one, then it will get uninstalled along with chef-client.

Comment: I used the command that "sudo gem uninstall chef";But I found there are also have chef in system at /usr/bin/chef-client; the command "chef-client -v"  is output “(Gem::LoadError)”,same as [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852242/to-specs-could-not-find-chef-0-amongst-gemloaderror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you installed Chef through rubygems. It requires **mime-types ~> 1.16**, but you have 2.0 installed. You should uninstall it and install the right version.

```
gem uninstall mime-types
gem install mime-types -v 1.16
```