# Using Chef 11 with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra

I had setup rails 4.1.1 with ruby 2.1.2 using rvm.
Now, on the same machine I have to configure a chef-workstation for my project purpose. I have a chef-client set up with following details :
OS- ubuntu 14.04
Chef-client version - 11.12.8

But, if I try to use knife commands from inside my application's ruby code, I get rubygems dependencies error for rails . Following is the dependency error i keep getting :

> /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find chef (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-4.1.1, actionpack-4.1.1, actionview-4.1.1, activemodel-4.1.1, activerecord-4.1.1, activesupport-4.1.1, arel-5.0.1.20140414130214, builder-3.2.2, bundler-1.6.2, bundler-unload-1.0.2, coffee-rails-4.0.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.7.0, erubis-2.7.0, execjs-2.2.0, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.4, hike-1.2.3, i18n-0.6.9, jbuilder-2.1.1, jbuilder-2.1.0, jquery-rails-3.1.0, libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux, mail-2.5.4, mime-types-1.25.1, minitest-5.3.5, minitest-5.3.4, multi_json-1.10.1, mysql2-0.3.16, polyglot-0.3.5, rack-1.5.2, rack-test-0.6.2, rails-4.1.1, railties-4.1.1, rake-10.3.2, rdoc-4.1.1, ref-1.0.5, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, sass-3.2.19, sass-rails-4.0.3, sdoc-0.4.0, spring-1.1.3, sprockets-2.12.1, sprockets-2.11.0, sprockets-rails-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.9, therubyracer-0.12.1, thor-0.19.1, thread_safe-0.3.4,   tilt-1.4.1, treetop-1.4.15, turbolinks-2.2.2, tzinfo-1.2.1, uglifier-2.5.1] (Gem::LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
>       from /usr/local/bin/knife:18

Any workaround

Comment: Could you post the any log of the dependency error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to separate the Gems installed for your different projects.

Answer (score 0):

To me, since it tries to use **ruby 1.8**, it seems that you have an issue with `rvm`.

Could you try this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356426/1991244) and tell whether that fixes or not?

Comment: yes. my knife works after rvm reset. But the problem is, then i can't use my rails. I want to use rails and knife in conjunction. That's where the real issue comes up, as rails 4.1 requires ruby version >= 1.9.3, but my chef installation uses ruby 1.9.1.

Comment: Can't you try to migrate your chef to use version 1.9.3?